# Reference error -Test is not defined in playwright automation with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, playwright

When I execute the code below, the reference error -test is not defined

```js
import { expect } from '@playwright/test';

test('Home Page', async ({page}) => {
    await page.goto('https://www.myntra.com/');
    const pageTitle= await page.title();
    console.log('Page titleis:', pageTitle);
    await expect(page).toHaveTitle('Online Shopping for Women, Men, Kids Fashion & Lifestyle - Myntra');
    const pageURL=page.url();
    console.log('Page URL is:',pageURL);
    expect.page.toHaveURL('https://www.myntra.com/')
    await page.close();
})
```

Comment: `import { test, expect } from '@playwright/test';` Import test before using

Comment: Not working bro...